# Rails test sending emails on request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using `rails 4.2.4` and I am trying to test that a email is sent in a requests spec.

```
it "sends a reset password email to the user" do
  expect do
    post users_reset_password_path, params, headers
  end.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :size).by(1)
end
```

This is resulting in:

```
end.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :size).by(1)

expected `Array#size` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

I'm sure my email is being sent because I see it in `log/test.log`. So my questing, is this happening because it is a `request` spec? If so, how can I test sending an email in a request spec? Is `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` only updated in mailer specs?

To provide more context I'm using devise so in the controller I'm calling `user.send_reset_password_instructions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my initializers were overriding the configuration in `config/environments/test.rb`. In mailer specs this is fine because `ActionMailer::TestCase` forces `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method` to be `:test`. In requests specs this doesn't happen.

Anyways I had to:

```
diff --git a/config/initializers/mail.rb b/config/initializers/mail.rb
deleted file mode 100644
index 4b8000f..0000000
--- a/config/initializers/mail.rb
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,10 +0,0 @@
-ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
-    :address              => "example.com",
-    :port                 => 587,
-  } 
- 
-ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

and add these settings to each `config/environment/` file.